# Substitution of a value on cell via VBA results to 1004 object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find the nearest value to a cell in the existing sheet, based on that nearest value (which is in another sheet), i want to fetch the corresponding vlookup result in the existing sheet.
The formula i am using is as follows:

```
ActiveCell.Value = "=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF(ABS(" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & ".xlsx]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & "'!$C$17:$C$100-B5*1000)=MIN(ABS(" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & ".xlsx]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & "'!$C$17:$C$100-B5*1000)),IF(ABS(" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & ".xlsx]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & "'!$C$17:$C$100-B5*1000)< 150," & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & ".xlsx]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & "'!$C$17:$C$100-B5*1000,)))," & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & ".xlsx]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & "'!$C$17:$E$100,3,FALSE)"
```

where `initpath` is the location of the second sheet which has all values. Column C has these matching values and Column E has the target value I wish to copy. i have a tolerance of 150 in matching these values. n/3-2 is the corresponding file number and freqcntr is another variable for file name... In all I have 56*3 files from which data needs to be fetched. file names are like "1 1550" to "56 1550", "1 1310" to "56 1310" and "1 1625" to "56 1625" 
When i directly put the vlookup, i am able to get the desired result, but when i write a VBA marco for the same, I am getting a 1004 object defined error.

Also another way of doing this without the macro could be, we use the file name reference from the existing sheet ( where file name is in column V):

```
=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF(ABS('initPath[&V9&]&V9&'!$C$17:$C$155-B5*1000)=MIN(ABS('initPath[&V9&.xls]&V9&'!$C$17:$C$155-B5*1000)),IF(ABS('initPath[&V9&.xls]&V9&'!$C$17:$C$155-B5*1000)< 150,'initPath[&V9&.xls]&V9&'!$C$17:$C$155,))),'initPath[&V9&.xls]&V9&'!$C$17:$E$155,3,FALSE)
```

but this keeps asking me to update the values for &V9&. Despite selecting the appropriate sheet, I am not able to get any result. Kindly advise.

Comment: If you are using Excel without VBA you are often forced to use extremely complex spreadsheet formulas of the sort you are trying to place in the active cell. With VBA there is seldom motivation for doing so. Doubtless it is possible to debug your formula, but looking at code like that makes me want to refactor rather than debug. Let VBA do the heavy lifting -- not spreadsheet formulas.

Comment: Thanks for the time John! The thing with VBA is it keeps giving the 1004 error which i am not able to figure out on how to rectify.

Comment: To elaborate what I mean by refactoring -- what you have is difficult to debug because it is all one big expression. It is hard to tell what part of the line is responsible for the error. In VBA it makes more sense to define variables for the various subterms in the expression and have several lines of preliminary code assigning values to theses variables so the parts of the expression can be individually debugged. Also -- if all you want is a specific value in a cell (rather than a formula) you can call worksheet functions directly from VBA.

Comment: here is what i am trying to do.... my target sheet has a value for length.... the other sheets from which i have to pull the data do not have the same length... but i have a tolerance for 150 mtrs.... hence the initial if condition in the formula..... later... on the selected value (which is in range of 150 mtrs either side and closest to the length in my target sheet)... i wish to do a vlookup and fetch the corresponding value. This works fine when i directly put the file and sheet name... but i have different file names (same as sheet names) for about 56*3 reasons

Comment: when i use the following in my excel sheet, it works absolutely fine...
        
=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF(ABS('1 1550.xls'!$C$17:$C$155-E5*1000)=MIN(ABS('1 1550.xls'!$C$17:$C$155-E5*1000)),IF(ABS('1 1550.xls'!$C$17:$C$155-E5*1000)< 150,'1 1550.xls'!$C$17:$C$155,))),'1 1550.xls'!$C$17:$E$155,3,FALSE)

In here the value "1 1550" changes to "2 1550" for second row and so on with every row... for 56 times and then 1550 changes to 1310 for another 56 rows.. & finally to 1625 for another 56 rows..
I want to use a macro to substitute this formula in all the 56*3 rows.. w/o having to do so for each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here:-

1. I agree with @john-coleman about the complexity of your expression.  It certainly could be cleaned up.
2. On a cursory glance, I noticed that you are missing a single quote and left square bracket whenever you specify the `initPath`.  This is the specific cause of your `Run-time error 1004: object-defined error` message.
3. You should be assigning a formula to the `Formula` property of the `ActiveCell` rather than the `Value` property.

Your code should then look like this:-

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF(ABS('[" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & ".xlsm]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & "'!$C$17:$C$100-B5*1000)=MIN(ABS('[" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & ".xlsm]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & "'!$C$17:$C$100-B5*1000)),IF(ABS('[" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & ".xlsm]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & "'!$C$17:$C$100-B5*1000)< 150,'[" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & ".xlsm]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & "'!$C$17:$C$100-B5*1000,))),'[" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & ".xlsm]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqcntr & "'!$C$17:$E$100,3,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Joehanna:  You nailed it mate.... Your syntax improvement helped me nail it.... Also, your inputs made me realize that there was a problem with my code where i was using the incorrect variable.... i was using freqcntr where as i should have been using freqSheet... which gets its value using choose operator on freqcntr